# S/MIME and Gnus/mu4e

Tags: mu4e, gnus

I want to sign emails with s/mime. The emails are created in mu4e, where message composition is based on Gnus.

The variables are set as described here

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusSMIME

in particular, I have set

```
 '(smime-keys
   '(("myname@mydomain.com" "/Users/username/.myemacsconfig/myCertAndKey.pem"
      ("/Users/username/.myemacsconfig/certChain.pem"))))
```

When I add the MML tag `<#secure method=smime mode=sign>` and then send, I get the message

`No sign key for <myname@mydomain.com>; skip it? (y or n)`

The `myCertAndKey.pem` file contains a certificate for `myname@mydomain.com`, though.

Is anyone here using Gnus or mu4e with S/MIME signatures, and has an idea what I am doing wrong? Thank you for your help!